# Move left by a word instead of by a character in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to move left and right by words using `ctrl + left/right arrow` in terminal (I'm on ubuntu 12.10).  Currently when I use these keystrokes I get `;5D` or `;5C` appended onto the line, which is useless for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glenn jackman's answer above pointed me in the right direction, and I've figured it out - add the following lines into file `~/.inputrc`:

```
# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

Answer (score 5):

Use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to go backward and
<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to go forward.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Line-Editing

Comment: Thank you, those keystrokes work for me, but do you know any way to bind the ctrl + left/right arrow to do the same thing - perhaps by editing in .bashrc file something?

Comment: Don't know exactly. Start researching the [bind command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-bind)